# MSXML2.DOMDocument60 - Reading XML in VBA with Namespace

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xml-parsing, domdocument

I am new in programming in Access and with MSXML2.DOMDocument60 so please accept my apologies if anything is not correct. I am trying to parse an xml but I am facing issue when loading it using MSXML2.DOMDocument. The structrue of the XML is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2021-03-11T13:00:47.000Z" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">InternalValues are used</log>
    </header>
    <managedObject class="RETU_R" version="EQMR20A_2003_002" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-503327/EQM_R-1/APEQM_R-1/ALD_R-1/RETU_R-1" id="136127888">
      <p name="angle">20</p>
      <list name="antBandList">
        <item>
          <p name="antBeamwidth">61</p>
          <p name="antFreqBand">1</p>
          <p name="antOperGain">185</p>
        </item>
        <item>
          <p name="antBeamwidth">60</p>
          <p name="antFreqBand">2</p>
          <p name="antOperGain">185</p>
        </item>
        <item>
          <p name="antBeamwidth">61</p>
          <p name="antFreqBand">3</p>
          <p name="antOperGain">184</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="antBearing">2800</p>
      <p name="antModel">80010825-2.1_L</p>
      <p name="antSerial">DEG3535443</p>
      <list name="antlDNList">
        <p>external</p>
      </list>
      <p name="baseStationID">45118</p>
      <p name="configDN">MRBTS-503327/EQM-1/APEQM-1/ALD-9/RETU-1</p>
      <p name="installDate">240814</p>
      <p name="installerID">CRCTL</p>
      <p name="maxAngle">60</p>
      <p name="mechanicalAngle">0</p>
      <p name="minAngle">0</p>
      <p name="operationalState">1</p>
      <p name="sectorID">3U21</p>
      <p name="subunitNumber">1</p>
    </managedObject>
    
  </cmData>
</raml>
```

I understand my code has Namespace which is possibly causing all the issues. I created the error decode Message in my vba and I get the following error :

> "Could not load the document: C:\Audit_DB\Input Files\Test1.xml
> Error when loading was: The element 'raml' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema."

Can someone advise how can i skip the namespace here and if there is anything wrong with the vba code. The code I have created is below:

```
Sub XMLRead()

Dim path As String
Dim firstNameField As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim lists As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim raml As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

Dim i As Integer
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
path = "C:\Audit_DB\Input Files\Test1.xml"

objXML.SetProperty "ProhibitDTD", False

With objXML
    .async = False
    .Load path
    .SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    .SetProperty "ProhibitDTD", False
    .SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:raml='raml20.xsd'"
    Set nodeList = .selectNodes("//managedObject")
End With


If objXML.Load(path) Then
    Debug.Print "Success"
Else
    Debug.Print "Could not load the document: " & path
    If objXML.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Error when loading was: " + objXML.parseError.reason
End If
    
Set xobjdetails = objXML.childNodes(0)
Set xObject = objXML.firstChild
    

Debug.Print objXML.selectNodes("//managedObject").length

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XML parser is trying to honor the document type declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
```

You can either provide the `raml20.dtd` file so that the XML parser can find it when it loads the XML, or you can disable the automatic validation and the resolution of external references (such as DTDs) in your DOMDocument (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760286(v=vs.85))):

```
With objXML
    ' ...
    .resolveExternals = False
    .validateOnParse = False
    ' ...
    .load "filepath"
End With
```

Both settings must be disabled, or the load will not succeed. Make sure you set them *before* trying to load the file.

---

That being said, `//managedObject` won't find anything because that node is in the `raml20.xsd` namespace, just like all of the other elements in your document.

You've already bound that namespace to the prefix `raml` (with `.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:raml='raml20.xsd'"`), but you need to use the prefix, too:

```
Debug.Print objXML.selectNodes("//raml:managedObject").length
```

Finally, your VBA code needs some clean-up. You set `ProhibitDTD` twice, and you call `.load` more than once, too.

Comment: Thanks mate, that works like a charm - I duplicated it as i was trying few things in a code but I believe it is not the real cause. Thanks for good explanation of how to select the nodes using the namespace prefix.

Comment: @Muhammad You can choose any prefix you like, BTW. If you don't want to write `raml` all the time, pick `r` if you want.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak , very helpful indeed. I have iterated through the node <managedObject> using for loop and then using  getAttribute("distName") to get the attribute name with "distName". If I have to loop through childnodes (for example <p name="antBearing">2800</p>) then do I need another for loop or can I use XPath to directly access it ? What is the best and efficient way to get to the childnode

Comment: @Muhammad There probably is an XPath expression to help you with getting get the right nodes in one go, maybe along the lines of `//raml:managedObject[@distname='something']//raml:p[@name='something']`, but let's not make the comments here an XPath 101. There's *tons* of XPath tutorials out there, it cant hurt to go through a few of them.

Comment: Thanks mate, i have managed to get through all the child nodes using for loop. I was just thinking if there is a way to directly access the parameter but it gets bit confusing at my level. The code has become slightly bigger but it is reading all the nodes/childnodes perfectly. Now i need to find out the best possible way to update access table while looping. Many thanks for your help

Comment: @Tomalak: You wrote ` If you don't want to write raml all the time, pick r if you want`. How did you mean that exactly? Wouldn't that depend on the declaration in the XML?

Comment: @UnhandledException No. Namespace prefixes are just shortcuts for namespace URIs. The XML can pick any prefix it wants, the code processing the XML can pick any prefix it wants. The only relevant thing is that both end up referring to the same namespace URI. (When you think about it, it would be nonsense if you had to rewrite your processing code just because the input file is formatted as `<ns0:raml version="2.0" xmlns:ns0="raml20.xsd">` all of a sudden.)

Answer (score 2):

```
With objXML
    ...
    .validateOnParse = False
    ...
End With
```

Comment: Thanks bro, It loaded perfectly fine. cheers